# IONCUBE in PhpRunner How To install

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, ioncube

i've been looking for an answer and i've tried a few ones but it dont seem to work, when i use a class that needs the IONCUBE loader it gets me the same error over and over.

```
Site error: the file C:\wamp\www\ProjectoInventario\output\include\multifacturas_sdk\lib\cfdi32_multifacturas.php requires the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the ionCube Loader Wizard to assist with installation.
```

i've installed the 5.1 to 5.5, even the wizard says it was installed successfuly, but the program gets me the same error over an over.

what can i do?

im on wamp by the way.

Comment: you probably just need to add the dll to the php.ini file. Then restart apache.

Comment: is ioncube loaded in php? Just having the dll on your drive isn't enough.

Comment: i have the zend_extension = "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/bin/ioncube/ioncube_loader_win_5.3.dll" on php.ini

Comment: is it showing up in your `phpinfo()` output?

Comment: No, it ist, or i cant find it, but why? even thw loader-wizard.php says it was installed, i put it on the php.ini and i put the .dll on the place, why does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Ok a couple of things you need to know.

1. You need the Thread Safe version of IONCUBE for WAMPServer. Thats the one WITHOUT the (Non TS) in its name.
2. Make sure you have the correct 32 or 64 bit version, the same as the WAMPServer version you installed.
3. If you are using WAMPServer 2.5, which I assume you are as you have Apache 2.4.9 installed you need the VC11 version of IONCUBE and not the VC9 version, which I think means you need the 5.5 version.

Once you get that sorted out, look at this part of the phpinfo() page to see if its loaded

[image: phpinfo page section]

The version will be different on your system, but this is where you look for the report that its loaded.

And last but not least, make sure you are adding the `zend_extension = ...` statement to the correct php.ini. Use the wampmanager menu to make sure you get the right file.

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This will edit the php.ini file in the apache/bin folder. If you edited the php.ini file in the `....php/php.x.y.z` folder that one is only used by PHP CLI and not by Apache.

Comment: Well, you are right sir, but i got the problem, that i install the 5.5 version, in the phpinfo it shows its loaded, and everything right, but in the moment that i use the Ioncube, it says i have to install the 5.3 version, so, i say, im gonna install both, so it dont give me problems, but that didnt work, and i got stuck on that, but thanks to you im much close to get to the answer.

Comment: You cannot install both, pick one.